# Discovered a pattern using higher order functions. What is this pattern called?

Tags: python, matplotlib, design-patterns, design-principles

I am working on a python project in which I frequently need to generate a figure containing two axes using `matplotlib`. The code to generate the figure is identical each time. However I am calling my own functions which accept an axes object as one of their arguments and modify it. I throughout my project, I call different combinations of these functions to populate my figure axes.

It then occured to me that I actually pass these functions themselves and a tuple of their arguments into a higher order function. The higher order function would have the responsibility of calling the functions to populate the two axes objects to generate my figure. I made a toy example to illustrate this below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def A(ax, x, a, b, c):

    y = a*x**2+b*x+c
    ax.plot(x, y)

    return ax

def B(ax, x, a):

    y = a*x**2
    ax.scatter(x, y)

    return ax

def C(ax, n):

    ax.axhline(n)

    return x

def plot(ax1, f1, args1, ax2, f2, args2):

    ax1 = f1(ax1, *args1)
    ax2 = f2(ax2, *args2)

    return ax1, ax2
if __name__=="__main__":
    x = np.linspace(0,10,10)

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    ax1, ax2 = plot(ax1, A, (x, 1, 2, 3), ax2, C, (5,))

    plt.show()

    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
    ax1, ax2 = plot(ax1, B, (x, 1), ax2, C, (5,))

    plt.show()
```

The function `plot` here is an example of such a higher order function. It can take in any combination of functions `f1` and `f2`. It then calls these functions on the given axes objects to generate a figure. The function `plot` does not care how many arguments `f1` and `f2` has, which makes it generic enough to reduce the amount of duplicate code I have.

What pattern is this? Is this an example of a decorator? If not does python have any built-in syntactic sugar to support this on a more fundamental level?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a ton of gain here. I personally think it makes more sense "flat", where you're just directly calling `A`, `B` and `C` in the main. If you were doing some kind of post-processing on `ax1` and `ax2`, then *maybe*. This is essentially just calling two functions on one line though using a non-standard syntax.

Comment: I don't really see a "pattern" here. What you're describing seems to be just what HOFs *are*.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think you might be right... its not that useful in this context to use a function object...

Comment: @user32882 No. Like I said, if there were secondary steps where the output `ax1` and `ax2` were needed, or preliminary steps where the pair of input data is processed in a certain way, this may be helpful. Passing two functions into a HOF can be useful in some contexts, but not simply to move where the functions are called. Keep practicing writing code like this though, because you may run into a case where you develop/find a useful pattern.

Comment: The closest thing is the Command design pattern, the only difference here is that you represent the command as 2 objects (function + tuple) instead of one.